# Evaluating git and merge doesn't seem to work the way I expected

Tags: git, svn, git-merge

I'm trying to evaluate if moving to git from svn would be a viable option.  I've heard that the merge in git works much better than the one in svn, but in my testing I haven't seen that.

Here's what I've done:

- Created a file called main.c

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>    

  function main() {
    int myNum = 10;

    printf("Hi, my num is %d\n", myNum);

    return 0;
  }
  ```
- git init, git add ., git commit -m "Created main.c", and pushed to origin master
- In the main.c file, I've purposely not adhered to a coding standard and named the function incorrectly.
- Another user comes along and changes the code to adhere to a coding standard (the curly braced is moved to the next line), commits and pushes

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>    

  function main()
  { //This was changed to a specific coding standard
    int myNum = 10;

    printf("Hi, my num is %d\n", myNum);

    return 0;
  }
  ```
- I add a function before main, commit and try to push and it tells me that my master branch is not up to date, so I do a git pull origin master to bring it up to date, and then I get conflicts

  ```
  <<<<<<< HEAD
  function main() {
    int myNum = 10;
  =======
  function main()
  {
    int myNum = 10;
  >>>>>>> f0aceffb16f0a24638493367f4be6f2a09e22a82
  ```

**Question**:Can anybody tell me if I'm doing this incorrectly?  Are there certain steps that I am leaving out and thus causing myself grief?  Perhaps I don't really understand how merge is supposed to be simpler than svn?

Thanks for taking the time,
Chris

Comment: Just because merging is simpler doesn't mean you'll never have conflicts. Conflicts are unavoidable.

Comment: have you changed the line `function main() {` after your push?

Comment: @JBNizet Very true.  I expect conflicts, but this seems almost too easy to not have just auto-merged?

Comment: @CharlesB The only thing I changed was the curly brace going from the same line, to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git cannot guess what you want when you have made two changes to the same line(s).  There is no SCM that can do that.  A human has to tell it what version should "win."

There are a few corner cases where git merges more cleanly than subversion.  I don't have them in front of me, but frankly, with a modern subversion, there's not likely to be a substantial difference in merging.

Your decision on whether or not to use git will not come down to some merge black magic.  It will come down to how git operates as a whole.

For me, what separates git from other SCM's is how it works.  Because it uses an additive model (new commits are additions to the graph) and each commit is hashed, it's VERY difficult to lose anything with git.  That complex merge go badly and result in an unholy mess you're not sure how you'll ever rewind?  Just `git reset --hard` to the commit before the merge.  Reset your branch back 11 commits and later decide that it should have been 10 commits?  No problem, just move the branch back to the 10th commit.  Decided your latest feature branch should have been based off of develop instead of master?  Just a few commands to make that change too.

Git's immutable nature and the hash of the contents gives me something I never had with SVN.  Confidence. Confidence that if I screw something up, I can figure out a way to get back to where I was.  Confidence that I can examine my changes and make sure they're right before sharing them with others.  I don't feel that panic of "Oh no....what did I just do to everyone?"

Additionally, while it's not something I use often, the ability to pull changes from another developer directly, or even apply patch files emailed to me is nice flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Merge wasn't going to be the end-all-be-all for the decision; just something that I was curious about when I was doing some research on why one would choose git over svn.

I appreciate the honesty in telling me that there wouldn't necessarily be any substantial differences in merging.

Answer (score 1):

You both changed lines that were close, and Git is prudent when merging close regions like this. However if changes were made in completely different regions then the merge will be done OK.

Some merge tools like kdiff3 will solve this merge automatically, and will be right most of the time, but I believe Git doesn't want risky merge to be solved automatically.